# WPF: program.exe doesn't exit "the process cannot access the file.. used by another process"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've worked on quite a few WPF solutions, and this is the first time i am seeing this problem.

Today it started happening intermittently. where after closing my WPF window, the .exe is still running under visual studio.

so i have to kill my program.exe manually in order to compile again.

Initially i thought because i overrode application start/exit/exception .. but i commented all that out, and it is still happening.

In fact, i see multiple instances of my program.exe in process explorer!

Can't figure out what is causing my exe not to exit. Is there any explicit dipose logic i can add in applicaton exit event to ensure it really exits?

My application consists of single window, and multiple user controls as views.

update

if i open in debug mode. and close the main WPF window, my visual studio does not stop debugging. however call stack window is empty.

Comment: Pause it in the debugger and see what it's doing.

Comment: the debugger is not running at that time. this is happening after i close the program running in non debug mode.

Comment: There can be multiple call stacks when you break. Goto Debug -> Windows -> Threads to see the various threads that are running. You can double click them to "select" then and see their call stacks (in the Call Stack window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event to log when your application shuts down.

Alternatively, you can [attach the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx) to your running instance (even if it wasn't started in the debugger) then pause it to see where it's at. Make sure to look at the Threads tool window, as you may pause outside the UI thread.

Comment: Attaching to the process and breaking should help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: that's actually a good idea, thanks. but when i pause, i get that "No Source Available" "show disassembly" screen.. Call Stack window is empty

Comment: You should be able to generate PDB files for your release builds as well, which should help. In theory, VS can use those even though it's a release build. Goto project settings/properties, Build tab, Advanced button, then Debug Info combo box.

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it, though its probably better to try to figure out the underlying issue.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Comment: I never claimed it to be a good idea, and in fact recommended against it. But it is *exactly* some "explicit dipose logic i can add in applicaton exit event to ensure it really exits."